# Can specifying a taskaffinity cause a new process to be created in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

So I have a very simple application.

```
Activity 1 
Activity 2 (affinity :mytask - launchMode=standard)
Activity 3 (affinity :mytask - launchMode=standard)
Broadcast Receiver
Service
```

1. BR receives an intent
2. Starts the service
3. Service does its magic
4. Launches the activity 2 which will then launch activity 3 after a while.

Now what I am observing is that when activity 2 is started, I see two process ids for my app. But if I navigate from Activity1 -> activity 2. I see only one process id.

My questions are:

1. Can specifying a taskaffinity cause a new process to be created in Android?
2. How is starting activity from the service different from the regular scenario when activities have task affinity?

Answer (score 0):

About question 1:

With the default config, specifying a taskaffinity will not cause a new process to be created in Android, unless you specifying the attribute android:process to be different from the default config.

About question 2:

starting activity from service, you must set the NEW_TASK flag in intent, and the activity to be started will look up in the system if there is a task with the same affinity has existed, if so the activity will launch in that task, otherwise it will launch in a new task.